# Get array of days by week number starting on Mondays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

For a scheduling application, I need to display the weekdays by week numbers starting on Mondays. So far I got to:

```js
var options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};
const weekDays = [];

for (let index = 1; index < 7; index++) {
  weekDays.push(new Date(year, 0, index + (week - 1) * 7).toLocaleDateString('nl-NL', options));
}
```

This code displays a range of dates given by a week and year, but can't seem to get it to start on mondays. Any ideas am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that January 1st of each year starts on a monday. This piece of code automatically finds the first monday of each year.

```js
var year = 2016;
var week = 1;
var index = 1;
var options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};
var d = new Date(year, 0, index + (week - 1) * 7);
var weekday = d.getDay();
var diff = 1 - weekday;
if (diff < 0) {
  diff = diff + 7;
}
d.setDate(d.getDate() + diff);

console.log(d.toLocaleString(undefined, options));
```

Comment: Not all days are 24 hours (8.64e7 ms) long where daylight saving is observed, so this may not work over daylight saving boundaries. Much better to add to the date rather than time value. `d = new Date(d.getDate() + diff)`.

Comment: I tried d = d + diff but that didn't work. Kinda odd that d = new Date(d.getDate() + diff) does then. I'll update my answer!

Comment: Well, *d* is a Date object and *diff* is a number, you can see what will happen [*in the spec*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus). :-)

Comment: Now I catch the difference between what you did and what I was trying! Thx again :)